# Mock write-verbose not working when with invoke-pester

Tags: powershell, pester

The below script works when ran with a dot but fail to run when called with invoke-pester (running Pester version 4.6.0).  Am I doing something wrong or is there an issue with invoke-pester?

```
using module "./Test.psm1"
Describe "Unit Test" -Tag 'Unit' {
  Context 'test' {
    It 'return' {
        mock Write-Verbose { write-host $Message }
        $T = [Test]::new()
        $T.createoutput()
        assert-MockCalled Write-Verbose
    }
  }
}
```

Test.psm1:

```
class Test{
    [void]createoutput(){
        Write-Verbose 'hello'
    }
}
```

Comment: The script runs fine when using a dot.  But when it run's using invoke-pester the  'assert-MockCalled Write-Verbose' return the fact it has 0 run.  Why would 'using module' usage impact the way invoke-pester function?

Comment: I've hard coded the path for the test.psm1 and the result is the same

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting from pester "Expected Write-Verbose to be called at least 1 times but was called 0 times
        9:             assert-MockCalled Write-Verbose"

Comment: I did some additional research and have posted a working solution now.  My previous assumptions were incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your mock setup.  When mocking for modules, [there is some additional work required](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Unit-Testing-within-Modules).

In action:

```
using module ./Test.psm1

Describe 'Unit Test' -Tag 'Unit' {
    Context 'test' {
        It 'mocks correctly' {
            Mock Write-Verbose {} -ModuleName Test

            $T = [Test]::new()
            $T.createoutput()

            Assert-MockCalled Write-Verbose -ModuleName Test
        }
    }
}
```

Also important, [read this note about class importing](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Mocking-with-Pester#mocking-a-function-that-is-called-by-a-method-in-a-powershell-class).